# Can't import @testing-library/jest-dom, expect.extend is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library, jest-dom

I'm trying to add `@testing-library/jest-dom` to my project with no luck. It is installed by yarn into my dev dependencies and imported in setupTests.js with:

```
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
```

The test fails with:

```
Invalid Chai property: toBeDisabled

  40 |     it('should be disabled', async () => {
  41 |       const button = screen.getByRole('button', { name: 'Create button' });
> 42 |       expect(button).toBeDisabled();
     |       ^
  43 |     });
  44 |   });
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: can you try expect(button).to.be.disabled() ?

Comment: @ManishSoni Seems the OP wants to use Jest for this test.  Changing the call would remove the error but would run the test with Chai.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're using both Chai and Jest in the same test suite, both of which have an `expect` function.  In this test you're expecting to use Jest but it's Chai that's getting called.  Chai's `expect` does not have a `toBeDisabled` function property, thus the error.

Are you also importing Chai in that file?  If so, remove that import.  If you need both testing frameworks I'd recommend separating your tests into different files so that in one file you're only running tests with one framework.

Comment: Ah I didn't realise they both have `expect`! That explains it clearly, thanks! I've changed it to `expect(button.disabled).to.be.true()` which works as expected. Appreciate that this isn't using jest-dom but your answer has explained the root cause.